# luaotfload creates corrupt gzip files

Tags: luaotfload

In our team we are investigating performance issues (much longer compile time and huge memory usage) when compiling big documents with LuaLaTeX. When looking into the font loading mechanism, we discovered that `luaotfload` creates corrupt `gzip` files:

```
[user@host]$ gunzip luaotfload-names.lua.gz
gzip: luaotfload-names.lua.gz: invalid compressed data--crc error
gzip: luaotfload-names.lua.gz: invalid compressed data--length error
```

Further investigations have shown that this happens since the `lualibs` 2.75 upgrade. Is this a bug in `lualibs`?

*Note:* The following issue and pull request regarding this issue have been created in GitHub, without any response so far:
https://github.com/latex3/lualibs/issues/7,
https://github.com/latex3/lualibs/pull/8

Comment: Turns out most of the team were not watching the repo ... now addressed ;)